# remove decimal but keep valus

Tags: excel, vba

Below are the code and I'm looking to remove the decimal but keep the values - is there an easy way to replace or remove the decimal "#0.00" but still keep the value?

```
Dim lCheckAmtCol As Double
Dim lNumCols As Long

'           Get user-supplied values used in this procedure

With Sheet1
    lCheckAmtCol = .Range("rSourceCheckAmtCol").Value
End With

'           Copy source column with check amount data to next empty column and format values as numbers with two decimal places

With Worksheets(sSourceSheetName)
    lNumCols = .Cells(lSourceFirstRow, lSourceFirstCol).CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
    .Columns(lCheckAmtCol).Copy
    .Cells(1, lNumCols + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Cells(1, lNumCols + 1).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#0.00"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly do yo mean by *"remove"*? What will eg `123.456` become? Will it become `123` (make it an integer) or `123456` (removing the decimal point)? Please clarify.

Comment: I just need the decimal point removed eg. 123.456 becomes 123456

Answer (score 0):

> replace or remove the decimal "#0.00" but still keep the value

The format is being applied in this line:

```
.Cells(1, lNumCols + 1).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#0.00"
```

Simply comment it out:

```
'.Cells(1, lNumCols + 1).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#0.00"
```

If you mean "I want the numbers with no decimals displayed" do this instead:

```
.Cells(1, lNumCols + 1).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will remove the decimal separator in cell A1 of the Sheet1

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A1").Value = CLng(Replace$(.Range("A1").Value, Application.DecimalSeparator, vbNullString))
End With
```

So `123.456` will become `123456`. If you need to do this in multiple cells you must use a loop.